# Firebase - duration of spark plan

Tags: firebase

I'm running a small scale application with google's firebase services. **How long I can extend with a google firebase spark plan.?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no time limit to the Spark plan. You can choose to upgrade whenever you want, if needed, but there is no obligation.